# Stencil scoped styles nested

Tags: html, styles, stenciljs

I'm not sure if this is possible but I don't know how to affect the scoped styles of a component inside another component.

We have the following components:

```js
@Component({
    tag: "gov-button",
    styleUrl: "gov-button.scss",
    shadow: false,
    scoped: true
})
export class GovButton {
    render() {
        return (
            <button class="element">
                <slot name="left-icon"></slot>
                <slot />
                <slot name="right-icon"> </slot>
            </button>
        )
    }
}
```

```
button.element {
    slot::slotted(gov-icon) {
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
}
```

```js
@Component({
    tag: "gov-icon",
    styleUrl: "gov-icon.scss",
    shadow: false,
    scoped: true
})
export class GovIcon {
    render() {
        return (
            <span aria-hidden="true" class={this.name}></span>
        )
    }
}
```

```
span {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

S následujícím použití

```html
<gov-button variant="primary" size="small">
    <gov-icon slot="left-icon" name="lightbulb"></gov-icon>
    Small Primary
    <gov-icon slot="right-icon" name="question"></gov-icon>
</gov-button>
```

I would like to affect the appearance of the `gov-icon` component in the `gov-button.scss` stylesheet, which is inserted into the `gov-button` component via a slot.

Unfortunately, with no selector I am not able to affect its appearance and I am not sure if it is even possible.

Thank you for help

Comment: CSS poperties cascade into shadowRoots, or you can use: CSS parts: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because technically there are no slots in the Light DOM and Stencil only "emulates" them when scoped is on. Scoped CSS in Stencil means adding CSS classes based on component name (sc-gov-button and sc-gov-icon in your case) to your markup and modifying CSS selectors accordingly so they are "scoped" to these classes. This is why this doesn't work:

```
button.element {
    slot::slotted(gov-icon) {
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
}
```

As a workaround, you can use the scoped icon selector in your button CSS instead:

```
.sc-gov-icon {
   font-size: 3rem;
}
```

Of course it has its drawbacks such as that you need to update them when you change component names.

Take a look how they use scoped in Ionic - they use it only for a few components where they don't want Shadow DOM for performance reasons.